# (Solved) Bone pivot point in pose mode isn't at the root of itself, but rather on the object origin

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones, pose-mode

[image: Thats the fail][image: thats the before]I am just learning how to rig my first character in blender and in doing so I found a huge isue when I joined the mesh and the armature together. Out of nowhere al bones pivot point became the origin of the mesh, and if I try and rotate any unconected bone (like shoulders, that are parented but disconnected) they rotate from the origin instead of the bones root. Maybe I'm missing something or I just have to change the pivot point manualy every time that I select a bone, but the tutorials I find do it naturaly without problem...

The .blend file should be here: https://pasteall.org/blend/f901534a6e6e44779789cb9212639998

Comment: could you please show an animated gif or some screenshots?

Comment: I'll try, one sec

Comment: In addition to moonboots' suggestion, consider uploading your .blend file for us to take a look at :) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hope that help, and thanks  <3 jajaj

Comment: Your Transform Pivot Point was "Bounding Box Center" switch to "Median Point".

Comment: If you've uploaded something on pasteall, you need to copy paste the URL it has gnerated after the upload

Comment: thank you so much Terg but, How can I change the Transform Pivot Point? srry for the noob question ^^"

Comment: found it, looked in the manual, I was trying coma but that is obsolete (it's period now) so, thank you so much everyone <3 this is my first time in a forum like this and I thought it would take longer. Sincerely in love with the comunity xD

Comment: @Blocius Hello and welcome. When the problem is solved you can post an answer so readers in the future can see there is an answer. After a delay of 2 days, you can accept your own answer IIRC.